# Show indication that a message was edited in mobile view

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

When a chat message has been edited at least once, we see indication about it in the ordinary view:

> [image]

However, on mobile view, there's no such thing: ([link to message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4746457#4746457))

> [image]

I don't think that small pencil icon would clutter the crowded mobile view, can it please be added?